# Why is my loss computing correctly as a metric but not as a loss in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am training a 3D U-Net and am trying to implement a Dice loss with Tensorflow. I created the following function, which can return either the Dice score or the corresponding loss `(1-score)`.

```
def dice_coefficient(_type="score", empty_score = 1.0):
    """ Computes Dice
    Args: 
        _type: "score" or "loss"
        empty_score: score if union is empty
    Returns:
        either Dice score or Dice loss (-score)
    """
    def dice_score(y_true, y_pred):
        # Flatten
        y_true_f = K.cast(K.flatten(y_true), y_pred.dtype)
        y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)

        im_sum = K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f)
        if im_sum == 0:
            return empty_score
        im_sum = K.cast(im_sum, tf.float32)

        # Compute Dice coefficient
        intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
        intersection = K.cast(intersection, tf.float32)
        return 2. * intersection / im_sum
    
    def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return 1-dice_score(y_true, y_pred)

    if _type == "score":
        return dice_score
    elif _type == "loss":
        return dice_loss
```

When training the model, I set both the loss and the score.

```
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss=dice_coefficient(_type="loss"),
              metrics=dice_coefficient(_type="score"))
```

However I get `nan` for the loss and a numeric value for the score: shouldn't the loss be `1-score` as defined above?

```
144/Unknown - 68s 473ms/step - loss: nan - dice_score: 0.0209
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented dice loss function to optimise segmentation of images. You can check out the code on this path https://github.com/charuu/msc-tooth-segmentation/blob/main/modelIO.py
The code snippet is below

```
class Dice(Loss):
      def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        y_pred = ops.convert_to_tensor_v2(y_pred)
        y_true = gen_math_ops.cast(y_true, y_pred.dtype)
        y_true = tf.keras.backend.clip(y_true, tf.keras.backend.epsilon(), 1-tf.keras.backend.epsilon())
        y_pred = tf.keras.backend.clip(y_pred, tf.keras.backend.epsilon(), 1-tf.keras.backend.epsilon())
        
        intersection = tf.keras.backend.sum(tf.keras.backend.abs(y_true * y_pred), axis=-1)
        numerator = (2. * intersection + 1) 
        denominator = (tf.keras.backend.sum(tf.keras.backend.square(y_true),-1) + tf.keras.backend.sum(tf.keras.backend.square(y_pred),-1) + 1)
        return 1 - (numerator/denominator)
```